How much does the ligand field splitting energy increase upon oxygen binding in hemoglobin?
In hemoglobin, iron transitions from a high-spin state ($S = 2$) in deoxygenated heme to a low-spin state ($S = 0$ or $S = 1/2$) upon oxygen binding. (This is the cause of the change in magnetic behaviour that I try to understand).
I understand this change is related to the crystal field splitting energy (\Delta) increasing due to the strong-field nature of the oxygen ligand compared to the weaker-field ligands that surround the Fe2+ before. Therefore the electrons pair up differently causing the different magnetic properties. Now I unfortunately didn’t manage to find any explicit numbers on why the field is so much stronger with the oxygen yet, (before there were already 5 ligands there, after binding, there are 6),but checking this would be really helpful so:
I’m looking for a source or calculation that quantifies:

How much the crystal field splitting energy (\Delta) increases upon oxygen binding.

The approximate value of the pairing energy (P) before oxygen binding.


Any references on what these numbers look like or how they can be calculated would be greatly appreciated!
One source for (what I think I understood so far) is:
Discovery of the magnetic behavior of hemoglobin: A beginning of
bioinorganic chemistry by: Kara L. Bren Richard Eisenberg and Harry B. Gray.
The following sentences are of relevance:

“Pauling did not have much use for ligand field theory (LFT), but, if he had paid more attention to it, he would have realized that the binding of O2 increases the energy separation between the 3d-L π and σ* orbitals, leading to a low- spin iron center, whereas, in deoxyhemoglobin, the smaller separation between the 3d-L π and σ* orbitals produces a high-spin Fe(II) ground state.”


This seems more like something a chemist would be able to answer.  Pauling was himself a chemist.  You keep asking about this on Physics SE and get very little back, so maybe try [chemistry.se].
